# Rails omniauth-google-oauth2 image size doesn't apply

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-oauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I'm trying to apply image_size to `omniauth-google-oauth2`, but everything I tried didn't work.

My devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, google_client_id, google_client_secret, {image_aspect_ratio: "square", image_size: 100}
```

I'm using my application_helper to display the image with:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def avatar_url(user)
    user.image
  end
end
```

If I check the image_url it still shows https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gg9KNrUy_97f3wDhevAJGE52nT8Y6ho48Uo9vJwHw without any change in size

I've also tried `auth.info.image.sub('?sz=32','?sz=100')`, but it didn't work.

Comment: I think with devise, it might help to wrap your options hash with `client_options: {}`, ie, `client_options: {image_aspect_ratio: 'square', image_size: 100}`

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery I've tried it, the image still doesn't change in size.